# Dynamic Arguments in Doctrine andX()

Tags: php, doctrine

I´m looking for a solution to **make the andX part of a doctrine DQL statement dynamic** according to passed arguments:

```
private function getDiscountPrice(int $weighting, Article $article, Customer $customer, array $args) {

// Get the query builder
$qb = Shopware()->Models()->createQueryBuilder();
$params = new ArrayCollection();

foreach($args as $key => $arg):
    $params->set($key,$arg);
endforeach;

$qb->select('discount')
    ->from('PhaBase\Models\Discount','discount')
    ->where(
        $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq('discount.kdNr',':kdNr'),
                $qb->expr()->eq('discount.pzn',':pzn'),
                $qb->expr()->isNotNull('discount.kdNr'),
                $qb->expr()->isNotNull('discount.pzn')
        )
    )
    ->setParameters($params->toArray());

$discount = null;

try {
    $discount = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
} catch (NonUniqueResultException $e) {
    // @TODO Add log entry to inform about Exception
    return null;
}
```

I want to build the content for the andX() argument in the same way like the Parameters, but I don´t know how to pass dynamic arguments to this method.

Thanks for any ideas,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Here´s the solution - just found it:

```
private function getDiscountPrice(int $weighting, Article $article, Customer $customer, array $args) {

// Get the query builder
$qb = Shopware()->Models()->createQueryBuilder();

$params = new ArrayCollection();
$conditions = new ArrayCollection();

foreach($args as $key => $arg):
    $params->set($key,$arg);
    $conditions->add($qb->expr()->eq('discount.'.$key,':'.$key));
endforeach;

$conditions = call_user_func_array(array($qb->expr(), 'andX'), $conditions->toArray());

$qb->select('discount')
    ->from('PhaBase\Models\Discount','discount')
    ->where($conditions)
    ->setParameters($params->toArray());

$discount = null;

try {
    $discount = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
} catch (NonUniqueResultException $e) {
    // @TODO Add log entry to inform about Exception
    return null;
}

// If a discount was found calculate the price for this discount and return it.
if (!is_null($discount)):
    $discountPrice = $this->calculateDiscountPrice($article, $discount, $customer);
```

Answer (score 1):

### You can `add()` additional expressions directly to `andX()` or `orX()`

Instead of adding your expressions to an `ArrayCollection` you can add them directly to an `andX` expression (and only add that to the main query if there are actually expressions inside of it). Same goes for the required parameters.:

```
private function getDiscountPrice(int $weighting, Article $article, Customer $customer, array $args)
{
  // Early out if there's nothing to do.
  if (empty($args)) {
    return null;
  }

  $qb = Shopware()->Models()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('discount')
    ->from(PhaBase\Models\Discount::class,'discount')
  ;

  $conditions = $qb->expr()->andX();

  // Instead of setting each parameter individually (see below) you could set them 
  // all at once without the need for an ArrayCollection(), like you used, because your 
  // $args array is already in the correct format.
  // $qb->setParameters($args);

  foreach($args as $key => $arg) {
    $conditions->add('discount.'.$key.' = :'.$key);
    $qb->setParameter($key, $arg);
  }

  // You could check for $conditions->count() > 0 here, but we already did that at the beginning.
  try {
    return $this->calculateDiscountPrice(
      $article,
      $qb->where($conditions)->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult(),
      $customer
    );
  } catch (NonUniqueResultException $e) {
    // @TODO Add log entry to inform about Exception
    return null;
 }
}
```

A little late to the party but maybe it helps someone else.